# Javascript array display only the searched item

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I would like to know how I can display the item from my array which contains 1 word of the item.

For Example:

My Array values:

```
[ "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6" ]
```

I search only "5", with

```
var ValueSearched = "Level 5".slice(-1);
if (Array.toString().indexOf(ValueSearched) > -1)
```

And it display the full sentence "Level 5" and only this one.

Comment: What is your question? Sorry, I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.toString().indexOf` is not the right way to search for a `substring` in an `array`, you will be treating the whole `array` as a `string`, which is wrong and will return the whole array value.

What you need here is to use **[`Array#filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** along with **[`String#indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**, to filter items that contians the serached word:

```
let matches = array.filter(el => el.indexOf(ValueSearched) > -1);
```

This will return the right elements that matches `ValueSearched` whether `ValueSearched` is the whole `string` or part of it.

**Demo:**

This is a working demo:

```js
var array = ["Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6"]

var ValueSearched = "Level 5";

let matches = array.filter(el => el.indexOf(ValueSearched) > -1);
console.log(matches);
```

**Edit:**

To return only one matching element, use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`, it will return only the first match.

```
array.find(el => el.indexOf(ValueSearched) > -1);
```

Comment: Thank you ;) Thats what i was looking for

Comment: @DorianGrn You are welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: Hi again, do you know if `let matches = array.filter(el => el.indexOf(ValueSearched) > -1);` display 4 time the same value how can i display only 1 ?

Comment: @DorianGrn Hi, in that case go for `.find()` instead of `.filter()`, it returns only the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), have in mind that this will return all values that match the search and not just the first one.

```
const list = [ "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6" ];
const valueSelected = "Level 5".slice(-1);

const result = list.filter(x => x.indexOf(valueSelected) > -1);

document.writeln(result);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9etnkrs8/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
filteredArray =[ "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6" ].filter(function(item){
    return item.includes("5");
});


console.log(filteredArray);
```